# ssh port forwarding with private key

Tags: linux, ssh-tunneling

I have an AWS cloud server that runs linux, to which i connect from my home computer.
So far I used to use Putty to connect to it (Windows) but I just switched to Linux for my home computer.

I am trying to figure out how to create a tunnel while using a private key to connect through ssh.

The example on the different doc website is pretty straightforward:

To connect to the remote server:

`ssh -i <key_file> user@xx.xx.xxx.xxx`

This does work.

However to create a tunnel the doc mentions

`ssh -L8080(portnumber):user@xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080(remoteport)`

But there isn't any mention of how to create a tunnel using a private key as in the first example.

I tried `ssh -i <key_file> -L8080(portnumber):user@xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080(remoteport)`

but it didn't work.

Can anyone provide the correct command to create the tunnel while using a private key? Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're conflating the port forwarding with the host (to connect to).

Formula is simply:

```
ssh user@host -i keyfile.pem -L 1234:127.0.0.1:2345
```

Comment: "conflating" = combine (two or more texts, ideas, etc.) into one.

(sorry, not native english)